# InvalidOperationException in EPiServer edit mode after deploy to Azure

Tags: azure, episerver

We are in the process of moving our functioning EPiServer 10 site to Azure.

After deploying our site to Azure, we get

```
[InvalidOperationException: This request has probably been tampered with. Close the browser and try again.]
   EPiServer.Framework.Web.AspNetAntiForgery.ThrowForgeryException() +263
```

when edit interface is loaded.
Error message:
An unhandled error has occured in a background request.

```
Unable to load /EPiServer/cms/Stores/notification/ status: 500
The page may not function properly unless it's reloaded. Press the button below to reload the page now.
```

[Screen shot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZKOA.png)
The site seems to be working 'ok' in spite of error message.
If browser is reloaded, the same error message is shown.

We are running: EPiServer 10.5

Comment: Odd exception, is web sockets enabled for the Azure web app?

Comment: Yes sockets are enabled. It seems now that we have the same problem in our standard test environment (not Azure) after upgrading to update 175.

Answer (score 3):

Check this configuration setting:

```
<system.web><httpCookies requireSSL="true" /></system.web>
```

If you  are using http, it should say "false".